# get list web method and display data in a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services, webmethod

I'm trying to display dates in a list box in asp.net. I have the following web method below and its working when inputting the student ID. How do i then call this web method in my page to display just the date in a list box.

```
 [WebMethod]
                public List<Attendance> StudentAttendance(int SID)
                {

                    List<Attendance> listofAttendance = new List<Attendance>();
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblAttendance WHERE StudentID = " + SID +"", cn);
                    SqlDataReader sr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sr.Read())
                    {
                        Attendance getdattendance = new Attendance();
                        getdattendance.ID = sr.GetInt32(0);
                        getdattendance.StudentID = sr.GetInt32(1);
                        getdattendance.RegistrationDate = sr.GetDateTime(2);

                        listofAttendance.Add(getdattendance);
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    cn.Close();
                    return listofAttendance;

                }
```

display date in a list box

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Session["UserAuthentication"] != null)
            {
               Student s = (Student)Session["UserAuthentication"];

                Attendance[] a = attend.StudentAttendance(s.StudentID);
                ListBox1.Text = display list of dates with the following format  ("dd MMM yyyy"
            //  lbAttendance.Text = a.RegistrationDate.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify registration date format in your web method like this.

```
 getdattendance.RegistrationDate =Convert.ToDateTime(sr.GetDateTime(2).ToString("dd MM yyyy"));
```

and  then in Page load you need to bind your list box to attendance list this.

```
List<Attendance> attendances = attend.StudentAttendance(s.StudentID); ;
listbox1.DataSource = attendances;
listbox1.DataValueField = "Id";
listbox1.DataTextField = "RegistrationDate";
listbox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i'm getting the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.Attendance[]' to 'StuAttendance.Attendance[]'

Comment: You need to use ServiceReference attendance class in list